# Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'enable_eager_execution' - with TensorFlow 2.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, eager-execution

I have TensorFlow 2.6 installed with Python 3.9.
However, I get the following errors:

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'enable_eager_execution'
```

When I run `tf.executing_eagerly()` I get False.

I reinstalled TensorFlow and I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: try calling `tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution`

Answer (score 1):

In TensorFlow 2 and above, eager execution should be already enabled by default. You can check that with `tf.executing_eagerly()`. Only use `tf.enable_eager_execution()` if running a version of Tensorflow before 2.0